# unique identifier for a device with cordova on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm searching for a good way to identify a device on iOS with my cordova application. I'm using [device.uuid](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid) but it's not a good identifier because after a new installation or update it creates a new [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). I thought about hashing the mac address of the device but it seems to me like there is no way getting the mac address of a device on iOS.

So how can I identify a device on iOS?

Comment: Apple blocked the use of the MAC address on iOS 7. You can use my identifierForVendor plugin, or you can pick the device plugin from github, that uses the identifierForVendor as uuid now

Comment: you mean this one:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

Comment: yeah, the ios code already uses the identifierForVendor. But it will only use it for new apps, if you used device.uuid before, it will return that uuid

Comment: but what if I delete and re-install the app will I get a new uuid with identifierForVendor plugin? Because sometime I need to delete the for deleting the database of the app on the device

Comment: if you delete and re-install it will change if the app is in development or ad-hoc distribution, on apps published on the app store, it shouldn't change